# Why does string not pass correctly to server when there is a '#' in my variable?

Tags: javascript, stringify

I am attempting to stringify an object but my url does not return correctly when there is a '#` in the object.

I've outputted the value of `JSON.stringify($scope.parameter);` and it is correct however the url is not.

```
$scope.parameter = '#' + parameter;

var url = $scope.url + '&functions=' + JSON.stringify($scope.parameter);
```

I expect it to be {"1":"i001::#11 object"}

but its actually {"1":"i001::

Comment: Show us the `$scope.parameter` before you stringify it

Comment: DaCuI’m rse the expected value is ‘$scope.parameter’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not encoding it correctly, so it's being interpreted as a fragment identifier (the `#` introduces a fragment identifier).

You must URI-encode things you put in URIs:

```
var url = $scope.url + '&functions=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.parameter));
// ------------------------------------^
```

Technically, you have to URI-encode `functions` in the above as well, but since the URI-encoded version of `functions` is, er, `functions`, I didn't bother above. But if it weren't necessarily safe, then:

```
var url = $scope.url + '&' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.parameter));
```

If the names you use in `name=value` pairs only have digits, letters, underscores, and dashes in them, you can safely omit the URI-encoding for them as I did in the first example above. (There are some other chars that are allowed too, but if you start getting into using those, just encode as in the second example for safety.)

Comment: @DaCurse - Not if the server is expecting JSON in the value of the `functions` query parameter.

Comment: Stringify is meant to be used on objects to turn into JSON and he's concatenating a # to the beginning of his object (supposedly), that's why I'm confused

Comment: @DaCurse - The `#` is just a character inside a string which is the value of the `"1"` property of the object. The OP isn't putting a `#` on the beginning of the object as far as I can tell. It's just that the object has a `#` in a string that's the value of one of its properties. E.g.: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/1oyvwj5x/